# DELETE ROW FROM GRID

Tags: grid, genexus

I have a webpanel with a grid on it. this grid is linked to a SDT. I've been able to add rows to the SDT, then automatically shows the added rows on the grid. Now I'm trying to delete certain rows.
In the event code from the grid's column I've put this code (taken from http://hmquiroz2.blogspot.com/2009/09/eliminar-item-de-sdt-en-genexus.html ):

```
&Idx = &Sdt.IndexOf(&Sdt.CurrentItem)
&Sdt.Remove(&Idx)
grid1.refresh()  //  added later, trying to update the grid
```

but the grid remains the same. I've tried adding a grid.refresh() after, with no avail. I've tried changing the "Web User Experience" property from SMOOTH to PREVIOUS VERSIONS COMPATIBLE. No luck neither. Debugging I see that the &SDT.Count property doesn't change.

Comment: Is the IndexOf method returning the correct index? You can put &Idx on screen to check the value.

Comment: Yes it is. I Have found the problem, finally: there was a.refresh() in another event in the code. That caused the grid to stop the update midway. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the folowing code to delete an item from a Sdt:

```
&Idx = 0
For &SdtItem in &Sdt
    &Idx += 1
    If &SdtItem.Line = &Sdt.CurrentItem.Line
        &Sdt.Remove(&Idx)
        Exit
    EndIf
EndFor
```

Comment: This works without the .Line. Already found the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Block of Code is working for me:

```
&Sdt.Remove(&Sdt.IndexOf(&Sdt.CurrentItem))
```

I use it in an User Event ("Borrar")